# How to list all arguments accepted by boto3.resource()

Tags: python-3.x, aws-sdk, boto3

Is there any way to list all the arguments accepted by boto3 functions i.e: boto3.resource() or boto3.client()?

Comment: You can look at the source code in GitHub. All commands are defined in JSON. See: https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore/data

Comment: You can pass the service name in boto3.resource('RESOURCE_NAME') . Check this documentation for more details. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html

Answer (score 0):

both `client()` and `resource()` create `Session` object under the hood (both call `_get_default_session()` that call `setup_default_session()` function that return `Session` object) and run `Session` instance `self.client()` and  `self.resource()` methods

So you need to check arguments of these `Session` methods:

```py
from boto3 import Session

print("CLIENT:")
print(Session.client.__code__.co_varnames)
print("RESOURCE:")
print(Session.resource.__code__.co_varnames)
```

```
CLIENT:
('self', 'service_name', 'region_name', 'api_version', 'use_ssl', 'verify', 'endpoint_url', 'aws_access_key_id', 'aws_secret_access_key', 'aws_session_token', 'config')
RESOURCE:
('self', 'service_name', 'region_name', 'api_version', 'use_ssl', 'verify', 'endpoint_url', 'aws_access_key_id', 'aws_secret_access_key', 'aws_session_token', 'config', 'resource_model', 'available', 'has_low_level_client', 'available_api_versions', 'client', 'service_model', 'service_context', 'cls')
```